# MySql Stored Procedure - ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I have written one stored procedure to calculate net product amount based on some discounts schemes available in database.... The stored procedure got compiled successful but at the run time I am getting **ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row**

My code is like below,

```
    delimiter //
    CREATE PROCEDURE calculateNetItemAmount(IN productId INT,IN quantity INT, OUT netItemAmount DOUBLE)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE discountPer DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;

        SELECT `SellingUnitPrice` into netItemAmount 
        FROM `TBL_PRODUCT_MASTER` WHERE `Id` = productId;
        SET netItemAmount = quantity * netItemAmount ;

        SELECT discDetail.`DiscountPercentage` into discountPer 
        FROM `TBL_DISCOUNT_DETAIL` AS discDetail , `TBL_DISCOUNT` AS disc, TBL_PRODUCT_DISCOUNT AS prodDisc 
        WHERE disc.`DiscountStartDate` < NOW() 
        AND disc.`DiscountEndDate` > NOW() AND disc.`IsEnabled` = 1 
        AND disc.`SchemeType` = 'Quantity Discount' 
        AND discDetail.DiscountId = disc.Id AND prodDisc.productId = productId 
        AND prodDisc.`IsEnabled` = 1 ;

        IF discountPer IS NOT NULL THEN 
           SET netItemAmount = netItemAmount * (1 - discountPer * 0.01)        
       END IF;

        SELECT discDetail.`DiscountPercentage` into discountPer 
        FROM `TBL_DISCOUNT_DETAIL` AS discDetail , `TBL_DISCOUNT` AS disc, TBL_PRODUCT_DISCOUNT AS prodDisc 
        WHERE disc.`DiscountStartDate` < NOW() AND disc.`DiscountEndDate` > NOW() 
        AND disc.`IsEnabled` = 1 AND disc.`SchemeType` = 'Volume Discount' 
        AND discDetail.DiscountId = disc.Id AND prodDisc.productId = productId 
        AND prodDisc.`IsEnabled` = 1 ;

        IF discountPer IS NOT NULL THEN 
           SET netItemAmount = netItemAmount * (1 - discountPer * 0.01)
        END IF;

    END//
    delimiter ;
```

Output:

```
mysql> CALL calculateNetItemAmount(1, 2, @RES);
ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row
```

Please help me...Thank you in advance..

Comment: When you use `SELECT ... INTO variable`, the query can only match one row. One of your queries is returning more than one row.

Comment: What is `SET netItemAmount = netItemAmount  (1 - discountPer  0.01);` supposed to mean? Is there a missing `*` in there?

Comment: Its actually.... SET netItemAmount = netItemAmount (1 - discountPer * 0.01);

Comment: Do you mean `SET netItemAmount = netItemAmount * (1 - discountPer * 0.01)`?

Comment: Use backticks when putting code in comments. Edit the question to show the correct formula.

Comment: Yes barmar... You was right... One of my query was returning more than one row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure, the queries that only need one row , just return one row.

For example, your query uses`into` sentence:

```
    SELECT `SellingUnitPrice` into netItemAmount 
    FROM `TBL_PRODUCT_MASTER` WHERE `Id` = productId;
```

There is a lot of reason that query will return more than one row (data inconsistency, duplicate records... any reason)

One suggested (but not recommended) solution is add `limit 1` to the end of sentence.

```
    SELECT `SellingUnitPrice` into netItemAmount 
    FROM `TBL_PRODUCT_MASTER` WHERE `Id` = productId
    LIMIT 1;
```